# NVarchar(max) to XML parse error

Tags: sql-server, xml, delphi, nvarchar, firedac

Have the following configuration:
Delphi XE7
MS SQL Server 2008
Connection to the SQL server with FireDAC

I'm using stored procedures to retrieve tables with all the detail records from SQL server in XML format converted to nvarchar(max). Here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspUsers_GetAll
  @ReturnData nvarchar(max) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET @ReturnData = CONVERT(nvarchar(max),
                (SELECT *, (  SELECT UserID, RightType
                              FROM UserRights
                              WHERE UserRights.UserID = Users.ID
                              FOR XML RAW('UserRight'), 
                              ROOT('UserRights'), ELEMENTS, TYPE)
                FROM Users
                FOR XML RAW('Users'), 
                ROOT('root') , ELEMENTS));
END;
```

On the Delphi side I'm calling this stored procedure, load it into an XML and I'm trying to parse it in order to convert it into a local list of objects. Something like this:

```
procedure TUsers.LoadFromDatabase;
 var
  usersXML: String;
  xmlDoc: IXMLDocument;
  workNode: IXMLNode;
  userObj: TUser;
begin
  Items.Clear;

  with dmApp.uspWork do
  begin
    Close;
    if Prepared then
      Prepared := False;
    Params.Clear;
    StoredProcName := 'uspUsers_GetAll';
    Prepare;
    ExecProc;
  end;

  usersXML := dmApp.uspWork.Params.ParamByName('@ReturnData').Value;
  xmlDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  xmlDoc.LoadFromXML(usersXML);
  workNode := xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
  workNode := workNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('Users');

  while (workNode <> nil) and (workNode.NodeName = 'Users') do
  begin
    userObj := TUser.Create;
    userObj.LoadFromXMLNode(workNode);
    Items.Add(userObj);

    workNode := workNode.NextSibling;
  end;
end;
```

In the above code the

```
workNode := workNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('Users');
```

line returns an exception somewhere deep in the Xml.XMLDoc unit. Not an error message with a specific problem I could fix. Did try with saving the xmlDoc into an xml file and it looks OK (can open it with all kind of tools like Firefox).

The strange thing is that if I change the @ReturnData into an varchar(max) I no longer get this error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For XML, avoid using * and unnamed columns.  Also, dont use ROOT in your nested XML, instead declare it as a named field. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspUsers_GetAll
  @ReturnData nvarchar(max) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET @ReturnData = CONVERT(nvarchar(max),
                (SELECT givenname = Users.GivenName,surname = Users.Surname   , emailaddress = Users.Email , userrights = (  SELECT userid = UserRights.UserID, righttype = UserRights.RightType
                              FROM UserRights
                              WHERE UserRights.UserID = Users.ID
                              FOR XML RAW('userrights'), 
                              ELEMENTS, TYPE)
                FROM Users
                FOR XML RAW('user'), 
                ROOT('root') , ELEMENTS));
END;
```

BTW I always avoid Capitalised xml tags, call me old fashioned.  Also note row tag 'users' should be 'user' as this refers to a single user.  This should give you

```
<root>
    <user>
       <givenname>Jo</givenname>
       <surname>Shmo</surname>
              <userrights>
                     <userid>12</userid>
                     <righttype>some_type</righttype>
              </userrights>
              <userrights>
                     <userid>12</userid>
                     <righttype>some_type</righttype>
              </userrights>
   </user>
   <user>
    ....
   </user>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I changed the approach long time ago so I can't test now if your solution is the right one ...